# JSDoc: reference @param of method in another @param

Tags: javascript, jsdoc, jsdoc3

I am new to using JSDocs and couldn't find an answer to this question.

Suppose I wanted to write this simple function:

```
function hasQ(array, item) {return array.includes(item);}
```

which with JSDoc's I would mark-up like:

```
/**
* Another way to call array.includes(item);
* @param {Array} array
* @param {*} item to test if contained in array
* @returns
*/
```

Is there a way for me to markup the word `array` in the second `@param` statement such that it references the first `@param`?

This is just a toy example, but I hope it makes the concept clear.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I did not see the possibility of writing related parameters (but see [parameters with properties](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-param.html#parameters-with-properties)). But you can write description ;)

```
/**
 * @method
 * @param {Array} array - description for this param
 * @param {*} item - description for this param
 * @description Please write your description for Method
 * @returns {*|boolean}
 */
const hasQ = (array, item) => array.includes(item);
```

Comment: While the answer is technically correct, it is written quite confusingly, probably a language issue. I'm not being picky but I had to read it many times until I got it was saying the same as the answer I posted.

Answer (score 8):

### Cross-Reference Parameters

Regarding `@param` as far as I know, **there's no way to cross-reference parameters**. As suggested [here](https://github.com/jsdoc/jsdoc/issues/1145) you can use plain English.

As a partial solution, you can use markdown's backticks to highlight the `param` name (as described [here](https://jsdoc.app/tags-param.html#callback-functions)), for example:

```js
/**
 * @param {*} item to test if contained in `array`
 */
```

### Sidenote: Reference External

There's a concept of inline `@link` to `external` resources in `JSDoc` that I guess would be useful here. You can make it clear in your description that for example your talking about the function `includes` of `Array`:

```
/**
* Another way to call [Array's includes function]{@link external:Array#includes}
* @param {Array} array
* @param {*} item to test if contained in array
* @returns
*/
function hasQ(array, item) {
    return array.includes(item);
}
```

Or if you prefer a link without a `text`, just remove the part inside `[]` in the first line:

```
/**
 * Another way to call {@link external:Array#includes}
 */
```

### Read More

In case you're interested to read more:

- [@external tag](https://jsdoc.app/tags-external.html)
- [inline @link tag](https://jsdoc.app/tags-inline-link.html)
- [@see tag](https://jsdoc.app/tags-see.html)

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do that. Source: https://github.com/jsdoc/jsdoc/issues/1145

Answer (score 1):

JSDoc has been updated recently. Now you can cross-reference parameter by using `{@link YOUR_PARAMETER}`.
Your example can be updated as:

```js
/**
* Another way to call array.includes(item);
* @param {Array} array
* @param {*} item to test if contained in {@link array}
* @returns
*/
```

You can read more about it here : [JSDoc Inline Link](https://jsdoc.app/tags-inline-link)